# Updating a matrix from list of redundant indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A`, a list of indices `is` and `js`, and a list of values to add to `A`, `ws`. Originally I was simply iterating through `A` by a nested for loop:

```
for idx = 1:N
    i = is(idx);
    j = js(idx);
    w = ws(idx);
    A(i,j) = A(i,j) + w;
end
```

However, I would like to vectorize this to increase efficiency. I thought something simple like

```
A(is,js) = A(is,js) + ws
```

would work, and it does *as long as the is and js don't repeat*. Said differently, if I generate `idx = sub2ind(size(A),is,js);`, so long as `idx` has no repeat values, all is well. If it does, then only the last value is added, all previous values are left out. A concrete example:

```
A = zeros(3,3);
indices = [1,2,3,1];
additions = [5,5,5,5];
A(indices) = A(indices) + additions;
```

This results in the first column having values of 5, not 5,5,10.

This is a small example, but in my actual application the lists of indices are really long and filled with redundant values. I'm hoping to vectorize this to save time, so going through and eliminating redundancies isn't really an option. So my main question is, how do I add to a matrix from a given set of redundant indices? Alternatively, is there another way of working through this without any sort of iteration?

Comment: For the record the answers from both Billbokeey and Luis Mendo worked like a charm. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emphasize a nice property of [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) (`accumarray` actually works with two indices)

With the example from Luis Mendo:

```
is = [2 3 3 1 1 2].';
js = [1 3 3 2 2 4].';
ws = [10 20 30 40 50 60].';

A3 = accumarray([is js],ws);


%% A3 =

%%   0    90     0     0
%%  10     0     0    60
%%   0     0    50     0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you only need `full(sparse(is, js, ws))`. This works because `sparse` [accumulates](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html#bul62_1) values at matching indices.

```
% Example data
is = [2 3 3 1 1 2];
js = [1 3 3 2 2 4];
ws = [10 20 30 40 50 60];

% With loop
N = numel(is);
A = zeros(max(is), max(js));
for idx = 1:N
    i = is(idx);
    j = js(idx);
    w = ws(idx);
    A(i,j) = A(i,j) + w;
end

% With `sparse`
A2 = full(sparse(is, js, ws));

% Check
isequal(A, A2)
```